# pip install pcapy subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, pcapy

I'm trying to install `pcapy` for a project, and this error is coming. I have all the updated softwares, and I use `wireshark`, so I didn't have to install `Npcap` as it was already installed with `wireshark`.

I'm getting this error while installing:

```
project> pip install pcapy --pre
Collecting pcapy
  Using cached pcapy-0.11.4.tar.gz (37 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\userab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rxr2phzf\pcapy_b23f9d11ae494894b9f0bb98cbc804e3\setup.py", line 49, in <module>
          save_init_posix = sysconfig._init_posix
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'distutils.sysconfig' has no attribute '_init_posix'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried reinstalling Python, ran the code in admin mode. But none of them seem to work.

I ran this command:

```
pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
```

It said requirements already satisfied.